# How to remove unused css in Rails without getting ActionController::RoutingError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, assets

I got the View called Welcome. I created this manually. And since I don't need css/js files for this view, I do not want to create and put them onto the assets folder. But, I then I got this error:

```
Started GET "/javascripts/welcome.js" for ::1 at 2017-11-13 14:55:39 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/welcome.js"):

actionpack (5.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
```

And this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/welcome.css"):
  Rendering /Users/ryzal/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout

actionpack (5.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
```

I could make these errors go away by simply creating the welcome.js and welcome.css files and put them on the assets. BUT again, I do want to do this as I know I do not want and never want to use these files.

So how do I solve this?

FYI, my Rails app did not fail. It's all working fine. The errors that I got were appeared on my Terminal. See below:

[image]

And here is the only thing in my `config/initializer/assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

Comment: Make sure `welcome.css` and `welcome.js` are not present in `config/initializers/assets.rb` .
Your app shouldn't fail otherwise since what Rails really cares about is just `application.css` .

Comment: @Vlad There are no welcome.css and welcome.js in my config/initializers/assets.rb . And my Rails app is working fine in the browser. The errors that I got are the ones which appeared in my terminal. See the updated post above.

Comment: Can you please paste your `assets/javascripts/application` and `assets/stylesheets/application`?

Comment: @RizalYusoff It seems that this js/css required either in your views or in your layout. Please paste your layout and one of the views.

Comment: @AntonTkachov there are too many files and details too paste here. But you can look at the files yourself here: https://github.com/ryzalyusoff/Quickrails

Comment: @bronislav there are too many files and details too paste here. But you can look at the files yourself here: https://github.com/ryzalyusoff/Quickrails

Comment: @AntonTkachov What? I have done everything I could and that is why I posted my question here with a bounty. Also have you looked at my github repo? If you looked there you can see all the commits that I have done trying to solve this problem. Your reply is rude and unnecessary. Since you also has done nothing to try solving my problem, I have flagged your comment as abusive and inappropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your layout:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
```

This forces your application to load assets for any controller with current controller name (for welcome too). If you remove this, your error should disappear. Keep in mind, that this code can be useful for other controllers and you can lose some of your styles/javascripts. Include them all in application.js/.css files in your assets. No need to load assets separate in such dynamic way

Answer (score -2):

There is probably a tidier way, but I would use layouts.

Assign the layout to the pages you want in your controller, and in those layouts require the files that you need:

http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/page-specific-javascript-in-rails/

Comment: I am sorry, but i don't think this is answering my question? What I am looking for is the way for me to not include the css&js files for the view in the assets without getting the errors